# Unable to view repositories after upgrading Nexus to version 3.1.0-04

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I just upgraded my Sonatype Nexus instance from version 2.14-01 to 3.1.0-04.

I followed the upgrade steps and everything appeared to work correctly.

The problem I am having is I can no longer view the repositories if I am not logged into Nexus.

Under Nexus 2.x, I was able to view the repositories and run searches without being logged into Nexus.  Now I need to be logged into Nexus for this to work.

Is there a setting in Nexus I need to update to allow users who are not logged into Nexus read only access?

Thanks

Comment: Hi there, can you file an issue with this text and your nexus.log while running 3.1.0-04 over at: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS

Comment: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11715

Comment: I solved this problem.  I updated the role of the anonymous user and added nx-developer, nx-anonymous and nx-deployment.  
Now I am able to view the content of the repositories once I am logged out of Nexus.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for letting us know here and there :)

Answer (score 3):

During the migration, a new role is created for anonymous user. You can remove that role from anonymous user.
You need to grant the nx-anonymous role access to anonymous user.
Change the setting from the Config screen --> User --> Anonymous --> Change the roles granted for user.